# Texture paint problems

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

[image]I'm having a problem when painting over a texture, in solid mode the color appears correctly where I painted, but when I put it in rendered mode the color doesn't go where I pass the brush, but in random places on the mesh, same thing when I brush the left part in the image editor.`[![enter code here][1]][1]`

[image]

edit: I noticed that this bug happens when I edit the texture coordinate and the mapping, when I change the texture size, but I still don't know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In *Solid* mode the *Mapping* node settings won't be taken into account, switch to *Material Preview* if you want them to be.